# Origin of the phrase “sweater puppies”?

Tags: phrase-origin

I am trying to find when “sweater puppies” started to be used in pop culture.  I have asked a search engine but only found a reference dating back to being added to the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sweater%20Puppies) in 2003 and I know it is older than that.

Comment: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22sweater+puppies%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) can't find any mentions.

Answer (score 2):

*[The Routledge Dictionary of American Slang and Unconventional English](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Routledge_Dictionary_of_Modern_Ameri/qX5aDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sweater%20puppies%22&pg=RA4-PA1693&printsec=frontcover)* (2018) traced the phrase back to 1994:

> the female breasts *US, 1994*:
>
> > One phrase sums up how I feel about them: Sweater Puppies - soc.college.teaching-asst, 2nd February 1994

[*The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_Partridge_Dictionary_of_Slang_an/bbcBCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=slang+dictionary+AND+puppies&pg=PA1796&printsec=frontcover) gives a similar example from 1992:

> Previous posts about her breast size were accurate. Un-be-lievable! Those puppies wanted out of that sweater! - rec.arts.tv.soaps, 14 September 1992.

As colloquial slang, I haven't been able to trace it back further than that in corpuses like COCA or in newspapers.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it was used before Usenet became popular in the early  90s. But it's a lot easier to search Usenet than to check barroom conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I remember it starting circa 1970 in Bar slang: "Look at the Puppies in that sweater"...AKA Sweater Puppies....Philly PA, Penny Gardens Bar.

Comment: In Philly, "puppies" is a term of approval for almost anything desirable. A valet parking lot attendant might say of Porsches that show up:  "We like to take those puppies around the block before parking them." Or someone might say to a coworker about a couple of Wawa pretzels on a plate in the coffee room:  "These puppies yours?"